# Add "@" before every word + ONE space between every word (JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript, html

I put together a code, in the **input** field one writes words and the **output** shows same words but with @ attached and have one space in between each words. The code I have so far is semi-functional, it kind of does what I want to do, but with some issues.

I am working on a few things:

1. I need to make sure that the output always has one space in between characters. If a user inputs (**types** or **pastes**) a sentence with MORE THAN ONE "space", the output shrinks it down to one space.
   As you can see:

   Currently if you input: tomato, orange, *(double space)* apple, it will output @tomato @orange **@** @apple.

   I want it to the output be: @tomato @orange @apple (remove the extra @, that was inserted due to double space)
2. When one deletes everything typed in the input field, the output still shows "@". I want the output be blank just like input if one deletes the input field.

Here is the code:

```js
function atPrefix (text) {
  return text
    .split(' ')
    .map(character => '@' + character)
    .join(' ')
}
```

```html
<textarea  id="specialInput" type="text"  oninput="document.querySelector('#output').innerText = atPrefix(this.value)"></textarea>

<p> <textarea
id="output">
</textarea>
</p>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `filter()` function to filter out any token that is only made of spaces:

```js
function atPrefix (text) {
  return text
    .split(' ')
    .filter(token => token.trim() !== '') 
    .map(token => '@' + token)
    .join(' ')
}
```

```html
<textarea  id="specialInput" type="text"  oninput="document.querySelector('#output').innerText = atPrefix(this.value)"></textarea>

<p> <textarea
id="output">
</textarea>
</p>
```

Comment: there's an issue with this if you type any special character and hit space a @ is still added, simply because splitting by " " doesn't necessarily mean its's a word

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work

```
function atPrefix (text) {
  if(text) {
     return text
       .replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ')
       .split(' ')
       .map(character => '@' + character)
       .join(' ')
   } else {  return text }  
}
```

So basically you are checking if text is not an empty string, and replacing multiple space characters with single space through regex.

Answer (score 1):

your code is good but after the split just use then array.filter(e=>!!e);

```js
function atPrefix (text) {
  return text.split(' ')
    .filter(word => !!word)
    .map(word => '@' + word.trim())
    .join(' ')
}
```

```html
<textarea  id="specialInput" type="text"  oninput="document.querySelector('#output').innerText = atPrefix(this.value)"></textarea>

<p> <textarea
id="output">
</textarea>
</p>
```

Comment: there's an issue with this if you type any special character and hit space a @ is still added, simply because splitting by " " doesn't necessarily mean its's a word

Answer (score 1):

You can find an explanation for this regex here: https://regexr.com/4qgs7

```js
function atPrefix (text) {
  return text.replace(/\b(\w+)\b/gm,"@$1");
}
```

```html
<textarea  id="specialInput" type="text"  oninput="document.querySelector('#output').innerText = atPrefix(this.value)"></textarea>

<p> <textarea
id="output">
</textarea>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

using regular express to replace ",?\s+" with " @" and prefix with leading @;
Do the string manipulation only when it's not blank.  this will address your second problem.